# Can't find 'jquery-ui' Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, gemfile

I have been looking everywhere to figure out this problem. I already downgraded the jquery-rails gem to 2.3.0 in my gemfile. But when I include jquery-ui in application.js I still get the Sprokets::FileNotFound error.

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
  (in /home/richard/projects/pickaxe/mini-projects/depot-app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:14)
```

This is my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I am dying to find out why this isn't working...

Comment: Did you add `jquery-ui.js` file to your project?

Comment: Can you post output of bundle install?

Comment: No i did not do anything after the bundle install. I thought this was taken of automatically..

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the [jquery-ui-rails gem](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails), you need to use `require jquery.ui.all` instead of `require jquery-ui`.  If you don't want to use the gem, make sure that you have a `jquery-ui.js` file in your `app/assets/javascripts` folder.

**UPDATE**

As of version 5.0.0, use `require jquery.ui`.

Comment: Be sure to get the appropriate version of the `jquery-ui-rails` gem for your version of Rails. If you get the 4.0 gem for Rails 3.2, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Hi @FabrizioBertoglio, ask a separate question :)

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I decided to check for you as other users may be getting the same error and I think it's part of my responsibility to at least update the answer if I'm made aware that it isn't the correct answer anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I tried downgrade jquery-rails on my application, That works fine.

1. Put `gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0"` to `Gemfile`
2. Remove Gemfile.lock -> `rm Gemfile.lock`
3. Run `bundle install`
4. Put `//= require jquery-ui` to `application.js`

> ```
> Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-08 13:16:50
>  +0700
> Compiled jquery-ui.js  (27ms)  (pid 7016)
> Compiled application.js  (148ms)  (pid 7016)
> Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (213ms)
> ```

Could you post your Gemfile ?

Comment: I think step 4 should be

//= require jquery_ui

not 
//= require jquery-ui

Comment: @Starkers : are you sure? have you tried using `//= require jquery_ui` . I have try using `//= require jquery_id` get error `couldn't find file 'jquery_ui'`

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm using a slightly different gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-ui-rails Still, I think one should use this gem rather than v.2.3.0 of jquery rails, as this gem is being updated. Seems like a better idea than sticking to an older version forever IMHO.

Comment: Idem, better idea using latest version and using `jquery-ui-rails` gem for jquery ui, but my answer for help OP, OP using jquery-rails version 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem was not related to the existing gems but rather with the cached version of them.

The following steps solved the issue for me:

1. Specify the actual versions for the affected gems
2. Clean the asset pipeline by running `rake assets:clean`
3. Clean your browser's cache
4. Start the server again

This process won't be the same for everyone as the issue here is tied to the cached version of the gems, as I've already mentioned.

At least it should help find the solution.