# Couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error even if I have jquery-ui in my application.js file

couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
  (in /home/jeff/work/projects/a/media/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:14)

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.validate.min
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: is gem "jquery-rails" installed?

Comment: Ya. I already have gem in Gemfile

Comment: use specific version of gem "jquery-rails", "2.3.0" or you can use gem "jquery-ui-rails" for jquery-ui as later version of gem has deleted the ui part

Comment: For me it works fine, 
gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0"
Please try it.

Comment: @Mohanraj,@Debadatt- your ideas work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use specific version of `gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"` as later version of gem has deleted the ui part.

**or**

you can use `gem "jquery-ui-rails"` for `jquery-ui` . For more information please visit the [git repository](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)

To require all jQuery UI modules, add the following to your application.js:

***for version 5.0 and more it has been changed. Please follow the [link](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#require-everything)***

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

**application.css:**

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

***For lesser version than 5.0 we need to write below format***

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Also add the jQuery UI CSS to your application.css:

**application.css:**

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */
```

Hope this could help you

Comment: If I put gem "jquery-ui-rails" in my Gemfile,then error comes as couldn't find file 'jquery'

Comment: i found that i had to restart the app for the addition of jquery-ui-rails to take.  steps i took:  1. added gem 'jquery-ui-rails' to the Gemfile. 2.  ran bundle install. 3.  added requires to application.js and application.css 4.  restarted rails app.  working well for me now.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate with current releases of jquery-ui-rails -- `jquery.ui.all` is no more.

Comment: Oh ! To all users. Be carefull between the minus sign and the dot sign between jquery.ui and jquery-ui between these two version. I have lost so much time on this tiny stupid sign. By the way, thanks for the response.

Comment: I wanted to upgrade `jquery-rails` to `~> 4.0.4` because Bundle Audit told me 2.x had vulnerabilities. Installing `jquery-ui-rails` worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 38):

I think you are using new version (your version > 2.3.0) of jquery-rails.

jQuery UI has been removed from jquery-rails gem,

- `≤ jquery-rails v2.3.0` still have jQuery UI
- `≥ jquery-rails v3.0.0` jQuery UI removed

Take a look [this commit](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/commit/2fdcdb2633cbc6426d412c050200fc31d14b9a3b).

**If you are using  `≥ jquery-rails v3.0.0` or latest version of jquery-rails**

You should use `jquery-ui-rails` gem for using jquery UI in rails, https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails.

In your Gemfile, add:

`gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`

and run `bundle install`

1. v2.3.0 < your version ≤ v4.2.1

   And put this into `application.js`

   ```
   //= require jquery.ui.all
   ```

   then put this into `application.css`

   ```
   *= require jquery.ui.all
   ```
2. ≥ jquery-ui-rails v5.0.0 or latest version

   And put this into `application.js`

   ```
   //= require jquery-ui
   ```

   then put this into `application.css`

   ```
   *= require jquery-ui
   ```

   or to use specific modules [read this](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/tree/v5.0.0#require-specific-modules)

Don't forget restart your server.

**If you are using  `≤ jquery-rails v2.3.0`**

see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16996710/1297435 for use `gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0"`

Comment: Your changes here seem more future-proof than a specific version of the gemfile. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with `gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0"`
so ended up deleting jquery-rails and only using `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` in that case you also need to delete 
 
`//= require jquery`
`//= require jquery_ujs`

from application.js, otherwise you might still get an error. That did the trick for me...

Answer (score 9):

The rails 4 answer:

add to gemfile.rb:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

add to application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
```

to add a specific module:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/yourmodulename
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I'm not sure if restarting your server is explicitly required but it never hurts anything.

Comment: Yes! Restarting the server fixed it for me.

Comment: Note when requiring modules that what used to be say //= require jquery-ui/draggable is now //= require jquery-ui/widgets/draggable
ie. an extra 'widgets' level

Answer (score 4):

I know its a noob mistake but I found this very frustrating and always forget to restart my app after I have installed something new.

Make sure to restart your rails server after you have followed the instructions above and it should work perfectly.

Comment: can't believe that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a noob mistake, but if it helps anyone..

I added jQuery-ui.js in my assets and then added the gem. Then deleted the js from assets, but my IDE also deleted the same files from the gem.

To resolve, first remove the gem and then run,

```
bundle clean --force
```

and then

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

It could just be a matter of restarting WEBrick or any other server you might be using so it picks up the new assets. For WEBrick just go to your terminal window where your server is running and `CTRL-C` to terminate the process, after that just restart it again using `rails s` or whatever the command to start your server is.