# rails 4 autocomplete gem issue, followed example

Tags: jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, rubygems

I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) in my rails 4 application for autocompletion. I've followed the [example](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) **very closely** but have had no luck.

First I required these in my application.js is this enough or do I need to go and download jQuery UI? I have jquery-rails gemmed and in my public/javascripts folder have jquery.js jquery.min.js, and jquery_ujs.js files but no jquery.ui files.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

Next in my reviews controller  (artist has a field called name):

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  autocomplete :artist, :name
```

in routes:

```
resources :reviews do
    get :autocomplete_artist_name, :on => :collection
end
```

and in my review form view:

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :artist, autocomplete_artist_name_reviews_path %>
```

When I try to type in artist names that already exist in my database, into the artist field of a review, nothing is autocompleted. I cleared browser history first to remove browser autocompletion and there is nothing working with the gem. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and haven't got anywhere. Is it because my review has a field that is named artist as well?

Answer (score 1):

As you had stated:

> I have jquery-rails gemmed and in my public/javascripts folder have jquery.js jquery.min.js, and jquery_ujs.js files but no jquery.ui files.

According to the `jquery-rails` [github page:](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails#rails-30-or-greater-with-asset-pipeline-disabled)

> As of v3.0, jquery-rails no longer includes jQuery UI. Use the jquery-ui-rails gem above.

So you can use an older version of `jquery-rails` or [`jquery-ui-rails`](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#usage)

[Please see this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830789)