# Upgrading Ruby breaks UI

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-2.1

I am trying to upgrade to Ruby 2.1.2 from 1.9.3 for my Rails app.

The problem I am facing is that the app's UI styling and layout has been destroyed by the upgrade. I can only see a white page with the UI elements (text boxes, select boxes) minus any styling arranged one below the other.

My `rails` version is fixed at 3.1.3 and my `jquery-rails` gem version is fixed at 2.2.1. I have tried to upgrade the 'jquery-rails' gem to higher (letting bundler work out the version - it sets it to 3.1.0). I also tried installing `jquery-ui-rails` gem with the upgraded `jquery-rails` gem as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830789/341008) and updated the assets accordingly. Neither worked.

What am I missing? What else should I be looking at? Google does not show anyone facing a similar situation.

**Update:**
I figured out which dependency causes the problem. It is `activerecord`. The Gemfile lists the following gems:

```
gem 'railties', '3.1.3'
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'activerecord', "3.1.3.patched", :require => "active_record"
gem 'actionpack'
```

If I try to move up from ruby 1.9.3, bundler complains about the version of `activerecord` - even for ruby 2.0.0.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
In Gemfile:
   rails (= 3.1.3) ruby depends on
      activerecord (= 3.1.3) ruby

   activerecord (3.1.3.patched)
```

If I change the version of `activerecord` gem, my UI breaks. Anyone know why this happens? Or, can anyone suggest a workaround? Ideally I would like to move to ruby 2.1; if that's not possible, I would like to move to at least 2.0. There are some gems I would like to use which do not support ruby 1.9.x any more. However, I would have to stick to rails 3.x due to project dependencies.

Comment: look in browser network tab for potential bad paths to css resources for a start

Comment: Either go to ruby2.0 and see what happens or start upgrading all your gems so they work with ruby2.1.  I'm guessing you use something like compass that needs upgrading.  Unfortunately you need more details for anyone to really help much