# Rails : Couldn't find jquery-ui in production (AWS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jquery-ui, amazon-web-services, deployment

I am trying to deploy a new version of a Ruby-on-Rails 5 application, including some AngularJS controllers.

I recently added some dependencies to my Rails app. I installed via bower the module angular-ui-sortable, which is now located in `app/vendor/components`, so that I can inject it in my angular modules. This module has jqueryUI as dependency, so bower downloaded it too.

I followed the instructions from the official repo : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable.

In `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, I also added two lines :

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require angular-ui-sortable
```

In `app/config/application.rb`, I added this line :

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components')
```

My application works fine in development (localhost), the problem occurs only when deploying in production to elastic beanstalk (AWS), I get this error :

> Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui' with type
>   'application/javascript'

whereas it checked in `/var/app/ondeck/vendor/assets/components`, where both jquery-ui and angular-ui-sortable folders are located, after the installation by bower.

As seen on [Couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830313/couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui), I tried using a gem but it didn't change anything.

Of course I asked AWS support, but they don't know Rails enough to understand what's going on, thus my post here.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance !