# Rails Asset Pipeline problems with jquery-ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-assets

### Update

I downloaded the latest version of jquery 3.1 and jquery-ui from the jquery website. Unluckly this problem with the `.effect()` function is not connected to the asset pipeline. I had all the required js and css files included, but `.effect()` would not work.

This problem is only related to Jquery-ui, while jquery methods work fine.
I am giving up on this, doing a git checkout and I will not use Jquery-ui effects for now.

### Summary

My asset pipeline was working fine, but as I wanted to use jquery-ui `.effect()` function, I noticed problems with the jquery-ui.css stylesheets from my browser console.

[image]

I tested this function outside of the rails environment with 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js and it worked.
I can **display** the **jquery-ui.css** file at `http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui.css`.

I did the following:

1. As my jquery-ui.js file also was empty I required `//= require jquery2` in my application js. This solved the problem with `jquery-ui.js`
2. As jquery-ui.css file was missing I did the following:
3. run `rm -rf public/assets` deleting the file in that folder (I also tried with `rake assets:clean`)
4. run rails assets:precompile in development and production
5. clearing the browser cache and using chrome anonymous browsing

This did not fix anything, but I can see the file and in production this problem does not exist. The application.css file includes the jquery-ui.css.
So maybe the `.effect()` is not working for the css, but for missing js files? The effect does not work in production also.

https://barteringapps.herokuapp.com/

Please follow the link above, with chrome you can test this function in the application.js file at line 18610, set a breakpoint and see that the `<a id="signupFacebookButton">` does not bounce. The effect is triggered by clicking on the big bottom "sign up with facebook".

[image]

I thought maybe I do not have the bounce effect, but I can see that file included in Development and I suppose that is not the problem.
Mozilla give me the following error "http:localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui.self-fingerprint.css can not be loaded" (i did not clear mozilla cash).

[image]

This is all what I know, the version of jquery I am running is v2.2.4 which is compatible with JqueryUi. My jquery-rails gem version is 4.2.2, while my jquery-ui version is the following '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'.

### Documentation

I have read and followed the instructions of the following posts
[Rails Assets Precompile just not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697604/rails-assets-precompile-just-not-working)

I read this one, but I did not run `rm Gemfile.lock`.
[Can't find 'jquery-ui' Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996569/cant-find-jquery-ui-rails-3-2)

Maybe my next step now will be performing a Git and trying to just include the jquery-ui files manually in my project.

### Code

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.3'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
#gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-easing-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs wwith ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'  

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "pry-byebug"
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'foreman'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Additional Gems added from Fabrizio
gem 'country_select'

gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 4.0'

gem 'fog', '~> 1.38'
#gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.16'
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
```

This is my application js

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.easing
//= require jquery.scrollTo
//= require jquery.nicescroll
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.tagsinput
//= require form-component
//= require scripts
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require wow.min
//= require user
//= require main
```

This is my application css

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
*/

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-theme";
@import "jquery-ui";
@import "elegant-icons-style";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "animate";
@import "style";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);
@import "line-icons";
@import "style-2";
@import "default";
@import "style-responsive";
@import "user";
@import "jquery-ui";
@import "main";
```

Main.js including the code to make the button bounce

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
    $('#signupFacebookButton').click(function(){
        $(this).effect("bounce", "slow");
        console.log("It was called");
    });
});
```

Main.css code for styling the button

```
.signup {
    background-color: #00ccff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 21px;
    border-radius: 100px;
 }

.fa-2x {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -7%;
    left: 2%;
}

.signup span {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3px;  /*11%;*/
    padding-left: 21px;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.btn-default:hover {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Gemfile.lock (relevant lines)

```
   jquery-easing-rails (0.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    jquery-rails (4.2.2)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
```

Comment: I have no idea about the cause of your problem (wish I did! Mine is very similar) but grammatically you should be writing "Developers working in exchange for accommodation". In a masthead, errors like this could make a huge different to commercial viability.

Comment: @RailsKiddie you were saying in the other discussion that the problem was with a plugin, so you disable all the plugin and found out that some javascript was conflicting? I am thinking of doing the same

Comment: yeah, when I removed the knob and kontrol javascript plugins the jQuery started working properly

Comment: @RailsKiddie tomorrow I will create a specific layout with just jQuery and jQuery Ui for testing. I will find a solution because I already done this with a normal html page, so If it does not work with the gem versions of jQuery, I will not use the GEM but the normal files, while if that is not the problem, we will be able to understand better what it is. I think the problem we have is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a testing controller with a specific layout.

Read more hear to create a specific layout
[rails assets in production not served (yet another assets issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791047/rails-assets-in-production-not-served-yet-another-assets-issue/42796635?noredirect=1#comment72865124_42796635)

In this layout I would use cdn version of jquery and jquery-ui and as it would work with CDN and not with the jquery-ui gem, I understood that a first problem was with the gem.

Downloading jquery-ui (which included also jquery files) and including jquery and jquery-ui in my vendor/assets/javascripts and stylesheets solved the problem

The other javascript files would not cause any other problem, but using this testing controller to test also the stylesheets, I discovered that a specific custom css stylesheet was breaking the jquery-ui effect.

I could solve this problem by removing the stylesheet, but a lot of nice effect where there included (as I am using a layout).

At this point i just started with chrome developer tools to uncomment all the css properties that the link had, so that I found out, by testing the effect which property was creating problems

For example the css property that did create conflicts was with the `a tag`

```
a {
    color: #28c3ab;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @RailsKiddie I think we can find a solution in a couple of days both for your and my problem

Comment: I encounter same issues with `gem 'jquery-rails'`, did you remove `jquery-ui` and add `jquery via CDN?